# Approximating $t\to f(t) = \sqrt{t}$ by polynomial and bitwise refinement, how fast will it be?

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, numerical-methods, radicals, computational-mathematics

Say that we want to approximate the function $$t\to f(t) = \sqrt{t}$$ on the interval $t\in [0,1]$. We know that polynomial approximation close to $0$ is very bad so we want to avoid that.

Instead let us say we find some polynomial which optimally in some sense approximates $f(t)$ for  $t\in [1,4]$.

Then we can use the identity $\sqrt{2^{2k}t} = 2^k\sqrt{t}$

In order to calculate $f(t_0)$ the idea is to find which integer power of $4$ to multiply $t_0$ so that $4^kt_0 \in [1,4]$.

We then calculate that value and adjust by a simple subtraction / addition in the exponent part of our floating point number, since a multiplication /division by an integer power of 2 can be done that way.

The question is, how efficient will this be in comparison to methods which already exist?

Comment: Splitting up the mantissa and exponent are likely done in hardware implementations already. Approximating the square root of the mantissa like that is generally not done as far as I know, since a few iterations of most methods will get you just as accurately.

Comment: The approximation error by a polynomial of degree $n$ would be (very roughly) $3^{-n}$, i.e. you'd need a polynomial of degree over 30 for double precision. That's very expensive, I'd say.

Comment: @ProfessorVector double precision for some reason I am unable to find good coefficients, maybe the reason is because I need to do the coefficient optimization for the coefficients with larger than double precision for it to work well. For single precision and smaller interval I can get a polynomial of order $4$ to work. This smaller interval can then be made to work with multiplication by some table looked up constant prior and after application of polynomial. I wonder if I can find some software which supports f128 or f256 linear least squares optimization, I doubt my current one does.

Comment: Least squares? I wouldn't use such a criterion, the maximal relative error seems to make most sense. But it's hard to find the optimal solution. I've never looked for that, just used a good and practical solution, like interpolation in Chebyshev nodes, say.

Comment: I've used the identity $\sqrt{2^{2k} t} = 2^k \sqrt{t}$ in a different context, namely using an extra int to get bigger exponent range.  I used the libm double precision square root for the mantissa, so this doesn't help you.

Comment: I tried it and it works great.